# Adding the portfolio category to the body_class on the portfolio detail page

Tags: themes

While on the portfolio detail page, I want to add the category of that portfolio to the body_class, but none of the solutions I found on the internet have worked. I believe it's related to the customized settings of the theme. The body of the portfolio category page shows the relevant portfolio category, but the category name is not displayed on the portfolio detail page. I am sharing the body class section in the theme's functions.php file below and I'm awaiting your assistance. Thank you in advance.

```
function add_body_classes( $classes ) {
            $current_theme = wp_get_theme();
            $theme_name    = esc_attr( str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( $current_theme->get( 'Name' ) ) ) );
            $theme_version = esc_attr( $current_theme->get( 'Version' ) );

            // Check is child theme activated
            if ( $current_theme->parent() ) {

                // Add child theme version
                $child_theme_suffix = strpos( $theme_name, 'child' ) === false ? '-child' : '';

                $classes[] = $theme_name . $child_theme_suffix . '-' . $theme_version;

                // Get main theme variables
                $current_theme = $current_theme->parent();
                $theme_name    = esc_attr( str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( $current_theme->get( 'Name' ) ) ) );
                $theme_version = esc_attr( $current_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
            }

            if ( $current_theme->exists() ) {
                $classes[] = $theme_name . '-' . $theme_version;
            }

            // Set default grid size value
            $classes['grid_size'] = 'qodef-content-grid-1100';

            return apply_filters( 'hiroshi_filter_add_body_classes', $classes );
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress SE. Your question is off to a good start but it still needs a little work. "portfolio" is not a core WordPress thing so please explain what you are using so we can better understand the difficulty you are facing. As a rule, questions where few, if any, guesses and assumptions are needed are much easier to answer.